# Domain-Driven Design - What would be the core domain of a music streaming platform?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, subdomain

I'm building a music streaming platform and I'm trying to apply Domain-Driven design principles.
I can't determine the core domain though.
The core function of the system is to let users browse from a list of artists, albums, and tracks as well as stream audio files to their devices.
There are other sub-domains that I believe are supporting sub-domains. Those include Recommendation, Statistics, etc.
What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm building a music streaming platform and I'm trying to apply Domain-Driven design principles.
> I can't determine the core domain though.

I think that the audio library is a separate Domain, but I'm not sure if it is part of your core Domain. Vaughn Vernon in "Implementing Domain-Driven Design" states that the core Domain is a part of the business Domain that is of primary importance to the success of the organization and that the business must excel with its Core Domain. So, this is up to you to find out. But, I would also consider the streaming functionality as part of your Core Domain and the library as a supportive domain.

The albums, artists and tracks don't seem to me as separate supportive domains, but as different representations of the library.

> There are other sub-domains that I believe are supporting sub-domains. Those include Recommendation, Statistics, etc.

I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

If you were the first one to build such a platform, I would say that many of your bounded context might fit in the Core category. But nowadays, there's plenty of music streaming platform!
Complexity is not the only bounded context's caracteristic that indicates whether it's Core, Supporting or Generic. You also need to consider the business differenciation factor.
That's why I really like the "[core domain charts](https://github.com/ddd-crew/core-domain-charts)" from Nick Tune, which helps you to find out in which category your bounded context belongs to.
In your case, your core domain, the area where you should put some effort and focus the most might be your website or mobile application. Improving the user exeprience of your application might be the only area where you could differentiate from your competitors.